# How do databases store live second data?

Tags: sql, database

So what I mean by live second data is something like the stock market where every second the data is getting inputted to the exact area of the specific stock item.

How would the data look in the database? Does it have a timestamp of each second? If so, wouldn't that cause the database to quickly fill up? Are there specific Databases that manage this type of stuff?

Thank you!

Comment: "...to the exact area of the specific stock item." - what do you mean by this? What is an "area of a stock item"?

Comment: like apple and the area in the database where the apple stock is located

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the sheer amount of money that gets thrown around in fintech, I'd be surprised if trading platforms even use traditional RDMBS databases to store their trading data, but I digress...

> How would the data look in the database?

(Again, assuming they're even using [a relation-based](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/%7Ezives/03f/cis550/codd.pdf) model in the first place) then something like this in SQL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE SymbolPrices (
    Symbol char(4)  NOT NULL, -- 4 bytes, or even 3 bytes given a symbol char only needs 32 bits-per-char.
    Utc    datetime NOT NULL, -- 8 byte timestamp (nanosececond precision)
    Price  int      NOT NULL  -- Assuming integer cents (not 4 digits), that's 4 bytes
)
```

...which has a fixed row length of 16 bytes.

> Does it have a timestamp of each second?

It *can* do, but not *per second* - you'd need far greater granularity than that: I wouldn't be surprised if they were using *at least* 100-nanosecond resolution, which is a common unit for computer system clock "ticks" (e.g. .NET's `DateTime.Ticks` is [a 64-bit integer value of 100-nanosecond](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks) units). [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date-long-) and JavaScript both use milliseconds, though this resolution might be too coarse.

Storage space requirements for changing numeric values can always be significantly optimized if you instead store the deltas instead of absolute values: I reckon it could come down to 8 bytes per record:

- I reason that 3 bytes is sufficient to store trade timestamp deltas at `~1.5ms` resolution assuming 100,000 trades per day per stock: that's 16.7m values to represent a 7 hour (`25,200s`) trading window,
- Price deltas also likely be reduced to a 2 byte value (`-$327.68` to `+$327.67`).
- And assuming symbols never exceed 4 uppercase Latin characters (`A-Z`), then that can be represented in 3 bytes.
- Giving an improved fixed row length of 8 bytes (`3 + 3 + 2`).

  - Though you would now need to store "keyframe" data every few thousand rows to prevent needing to re-play every trade from the very beginning to get the current price.
- If data is physically partitioned by symbol (i.e.. using a separate file on disk for each symbol) then you don't need to include the symbol in the record at all, bringing the row length down to merely **5 bytes**.

> If so, wouldn't that cause the database to quickly fill up?

No, not really (at least assuming you're using HDDs made since the early 2000s); consider that:

- Major stock-exchanges really don't have *that many* stocks, e.g. NASDAQ only has a few thousand stocks ([5,015](https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/screener) apparently).
- While high-profile stocks (APPL, AMD, MSFT, etc) typically have 30-day sales volumes on the order of 20-130m, that's [only the most popular ~50 stocks](https://finance.yahoo.com/most-active/?count=25&offset=0), most stocks have 30-day volumes far below that.

  - Let's just assume all 5,000 stocks all have a 30-day volume of 3m.
  - That's ~100,000 trades per day, per stock on average.
  - That would require `100,000 * 16 bytes` per day per stock.

    - That's `1,600,000 bytes` per day per stock.
    - Or `1.5MiB` per day per stock.

      - `556MiB` per year per stock.
  - For the entire exchange (of 5,000 stocks) that's `7.5GiB/day`.

    - Or `2.7TB/year`.
  - When using deltas instead of absolute values, then the storage space requirements are halved to `~278MiB/year` per stock, or `1.39TB/year` for the entire exchange.
- In practice, historical information would be likely be archived and compressed (likely using a column-major approach to make them more amenable to good compression with general purpose compression schemes, and if data is grouped by symbol then that shaves off another 4 bytes).

  - Even without compression, partitioning by symbol and using deltas means needing around only `870GB/year` for the entire exchange.

    - That's small enough to fit into a $40 HDD drive from Amazon.

> Are there specific Databases that manage this type of stuff?

Undoubtedly, but I don't think they'd need to optimize for storage-space specifically - more likely write-performance and security.

Answer (score 1):

They use different big data architectures like [Kappa and Lambda](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-brief-introduction-to-two-data-processing-architectures-lambda-and-kappa-for-big-data-4f35c28005bb) where data is processed in both near real-time and batch pipelines, in this case  live second data is "stored" in a messaging engine like [Apache Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/intro) and then it's retrieved, processed and ingested to databases with streaming processing engines like [Apache Spark Streaming](https://databricks.com/glossary/what-is-spark-streaming)

They often don't use RDMBS databases like MySQL, SQL Server and so forth to store the data and instead they use NoSQL data storage or  formats like Apache Avro or Apache Parquet stored in buckets like AWS S3 or Google Cloud Storage properly partitioned to improve performance.

A full example can be found here: [Streaming Architecture with Apache Spark and Kafka](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/streaming-architecture-apache-spark-kafka-abilash-thulasidharan?trk=public_profile_article_view)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Kafka, and similar event-sourcing engines are [not databases though](https://materialize.com/kafka-is-not-a-database/) - while they _can_ retain data indefinitely, it isn't how they're intended to be used.

Comment: @Dai Yes, I did not try to say that, I tried to say that there are two big data architectures that handle real time processing like stock market that relies on event-sourcing engines like kafka, I edited my answer to give a further explanation